# Is it possible to find the domain and range of a circle function without graphing it?

Tags: functions, circles

If I am given a circle, such as, $(x + 1)^2 + y^2 = 9$, is it possible to determine the domain and range without having to graph it up? I know the answer, but I don't see any connection with that and the equation. I know for functions such as $x^2 + y^2 = 9$ the domain and range is simply -3, 3 but the equation above is not in that form.

Comment: The domain and range of what exactly?

Comment: Try solving for $y$. That'll give you a way to tell what the range of values of $y$ are.

Comment: In general domain and range are properties of a **function**.  What is the function here?  A circle is not the graph of a function, because it fails the vertical-line test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining $x'=x+1$, the equation becomes $x'^2+y^2=9$, that you know how to handle.

The domain of $x'$ being $-3, 3$, that of $x$ is $-4, 2$.

More generally, to find the domain of such an implicit function, you have to check for what values of $x$ is has solutions.

In this case, $(x+1)^2+y^2=9$ can be written as $y^2=9-(x+1)^2$, which makes sense only if $0\le9-(x+1)^2$ (because $y^2$ cannot be negative), or $(x+1)^2\le9$.
$$-3\le x+1\le3.$$$$-4\le x\le2.$$
Very similarly for the range, $(x+1)^2=9-y^2$, so that $0\le9-y^2$.
$$-3\le y\le3.$$
Let us take the case of a general conic, $ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f=0$. You can see that as a second degree equation in $y$:
$$cy^2+(bx+e)y+(ax^2+dx+f)=0.$$
It has real solutions when the discriminant is positive, i.e.
$$(bx+e)^2-4c(ax^2+dx+f)\ge 0,$$
$$(b^2-4ca)x^2+2(be-2cd)x+(e^2-4cf)\ge 0.$$
You now have to discuss the roots of this second degree equation in $x$, again based on its discriminant
$$4(be-2cd)^2-4(b^2-4ca)(e^2-4cf).$$

Answer (score 0):

$(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 = r^2$ is a circle with center at $(a, b)$ and radius $r$, so domain is $[a-r, a+r]$ and range is $[b-r, b+r]$.

Comment: In my case, a = 1, r = 9, 1 - 9 is not equal to the correct answer, can you please explain your method?

Comment: Be careful — you do not have $r=9$. You have $r^2=9$, so $r=3$.